# C# List replacement values for input string - Quickest way

Tags: c#, regex, replace, lambda, lookup

I have a static list of MyObj which is dynamically populated from a json file.

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string OriginalValue { get; set; } = "";
    public string ReplacementValue { get; set; } = "";
}
```

I will populate the list with foo values for the sake of this question.

```
public static List<MyObj> ReplacementValues = new MyObj[]
{
    new MyObj() { OriginalValue = "{a}",  ReplacementValue = "Queen" },
    new MyObj() { OriginalValue = "{m}",  ReplacementValue = "Cersei" },
    new MyObj() { OriginalValue = "{s1}", ReplacementValue = "Khaleesi" },
    new MyObj() { OriginalValue = "{p}",  ReplacementValue = "Harry" },
    ...
    new MyObj() { OriginalValue = "{_2_29sa}",  ReplacementValue = "229Z" }
}.ToList();
```

I then have an input string (could be anything really, multiples of the same {x} value, 30x times):

`var inputstring = "The Khal is looking for a {a}, her name must not be {m}. He found one called {s1}. {p} Potter {p}{p}{p}{p}{p}{p}";`

In what way can I quickly iterate through the values, replacing the values in the string with the replacement value.

I can do a `foreach` loop with `indexOf`'s etc. and iterate through the static list, but the list could get pretty big, lets say 15000 entries big. I know it doesn't sound like much, but the replacement should be close to realtime'ish, and if there are 400x of the same value in the input string, Could end up looping so many times through the 15k list.

Is there a faster lambda or Regex way of quickly replacing the values in the string with those in the lookup list?

Comment: What about [string.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)? It would require a pass for each substitution, but dang would it be easy!

Comment: So loop through the big list once, and use string.Replace for each entry?

Comment: consider using a Dictionary<string, string> (or Dictionary<string, MyObj> where the key is the original value (provided they are unique) and the value is the replacement string (or the MyObj instance the key pertains to). Then there is no need to iterate the collection, instead you can get the replacement value using: myDict[key].Value (or myDict[key].Value.ReplacementValue;)

Comment: The Dictionary sounds great. But then would still need to search for a string withing it. The string could be something like `Yes, {a} is good, {some {soe` How would I or the code know that only {a} exists in the list and that the other curleys are just for show?

Comment: What is the expected average length of the string to be examined for replacement tags?

Comment: anything from 1 char to 400 chars. And it doesn't necessarily contain the values in the static list

Comment: Well I think it would be better to do a scan of this input list finding the {???} tags and then taking the value from the value associated to the dictionary key and execute a replace

Comment: Check [this solution](http://ideone.com/6693d4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the `Regex.Replace` with a `MatchEvaluator` delegate is the best choice:

```
var dictReplacement = ReplacementValues.ToDictionary(rv => rv.OriginalValue, rv => rv.ReplacementValue);

var ans = Regex.Replace(inputstring, @"\{.+?\}", m => dictReplacement.ContainsKey(m.Value) ? dictReplacement[m.Value] : m.Value);
```

If you have C# 7.0, you can use this instead:

```
var ans = Regex.Replace(inputstring, @"\{.+?\}", m => dictReplacement.TryGetValue(m.Value, out var subst) ? subst : m.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that your list could have so many distinct objects I think it is better to scan your much shorter input string and then replace just the tags you find there.

You could combine this with the fast retrieval time of a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"{a}", "the new hero"},
    {"{b}", "of the new era"}
};
.....

string input = GetInputString();
int posStart = 0;
while ((posStart = input.IndexOf("{", posStart)) != -1)
{
    int posEnd = replacements.IndexOf("}", posStart+1);
    if(posEnd == -1)
        break;

    string sub = input.Substring(posStart, posEnd+1-posStart);
    if(test.ContainsKey(sub))
        input = input.Replace(sub, test[sub]);
    posStart++;
}
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is a `foreach` loop using `String.Replace`.

```
foreach(var r in ReplacementValues)
{
      inputString.Replace(r.OriginalValue, r.ReplacementValue);
}
```

or you can simplify this (note this is less efficient):

```
ReplacementValues.ForEach(r => inputList.Replace(r.OriginalValue, r.ReplacementValue);
```

Comment: Why do you say the second is less efficient? Functionally it's exactly the same.